# Compose : how to stock a list of composable files

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to make a list of all the elements I would draw in my composable fragment. And make it as easy to maintain as possible.

So I thought, I should not put the list of elements inside my fragment, but outside, in a class that will stock and order those elements.
Here is the solution I came with :

```
    interface SimpleDraw {
    @Composable
    fun Draw()
}
```

Create differentes implementation of my interface

```
class WelcomeBottomSheetElementsImpl : WelcomeBottomSheetElements {

    override fun listOfItemInBottomSheet(): List<SimpleDraw> {
        return listOf(
insiert here my list of instances of my interface)

fun LazyListScope.BottomsheetBody(
    welcomeElements: List<SimpleDraw>,
    clickViewModel: ClickViewModel
) {
    items(items = welcomeElements) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, top = 5.dp)
        ) {
            it.Draw()
        }
    }
}
```

So far it works great ! Produces the result I was looking at, but it feels off. It feels like this is not the way to do it in Compose.

Is this way correct or am I wrong ?